# How to subset a tsv file based on a pattern?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have two files. One file is a tab separated file containing multiple columns. the other file is a list of gene names. I have to extract only those rows which have the genes listed in file 2 are present in file 1. 
I tried the below command but it extract all the rows:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next} {for(i in a){if($10~i){print;break}}}' File2 file1
```

**File1:**

`Input line      ID      Chrom   Position        Strand  Ref. base(s)    Alt. base(s)    Sample ID       HUGO symbol     Sequence ontology       Protein sequen
3       VAR113_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    11082255        +       G       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA TARDBP  MS      K263N   .       PASS    het     3       25
4       VAR114_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    15545868        +       G       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA TMEM51  MS      V131F   .       PASS    het     3       13
6       VAR116_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    20676680        +       C       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA VWA5B1  SY      S970S   .       PASS    het     4       34
7       rs149021429_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA     chr1    21554495        +       C       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA ECE1    SY      S570S   .       PASS    het     3
16      VAR126_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    39905109        +       C       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA MACF1   SY      V4069V  .       PASS    het     4       17
21      VAR131_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    101387378       +       G       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA SLC30A7 MS      A275S   .       PASS    het     4       45
24      VAR134_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    113256156       +       C       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA PPM1J   MS      S135I   .       PASS    het     3       9
25      rs201097299_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA     chr1    145326106       +       A       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA NBPF10  MS      M1327L  .       PASS    het     5
26      VAR136_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    149859281       +       T       C       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA HIST2H2AB       SY      E62E    .       PASS    het     11
27      VAR137_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    150529801       +       C       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA ADAMTSL4        SY      S679S   .       PASS    het     3
28      rs376491237_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA     chr1    150532649       +       C       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA ADAMTSL4        SY      R1068R  .       PASS    het
34      VAR144_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    160389277       +       T       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA VANGL2  SY      L226L   .       PASS    het     3       6
35      VAR145_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    161012389       +       C       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA USF1    MS      D44Y    .       PASS    het     3       32
37      VAR147_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    200954042       +       G       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA KIF21B  MS      R1250S  .       PASS    het     3       21
41      rs191896925_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA     chr1    207760805       +       G       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA CR1     MS      G1869W  .       PASS    het     3
42      VAR152_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    208218427       +       C       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA PLXNA2  SY      G1208G  .       PASS    het     3       13
43      VAR153_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    222715425       +       A       G       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA HHIPL2  SY      Y349Y   .       PASS    het     10      41
44      VAR154_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    222715452       +       T       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA HHIPL2  SY      G340G   .       PASS    het     5       46
45      VAR155_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr1    223568296       +       G       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA C1orf65 SY      G493G   .       PASS    het     3       25
48      VAR158_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr2    8931258 +       G       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA KIDINS220       MS      P458L   .       PASS    het     3       13
51      VAR161_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr2    37229656        +       C       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA HEATR5B MS      G1704C  .       PASS    het     4       9
60      VAR170_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr2    84775506        +       G       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA DNAH6   MS      Q427H   .       PASS    het     3       20
63      VAR173_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr2    86378563        +       C       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA IMMT    MS      A420S   .       PASS    het     6       29
64      VAR174_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr2    86716546        +       G       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA KDM3A   MS      C1140F  .       PASS    het     3       18
65      VAR175_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr2    96852612        +       C       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA STARD7  SY      L323L   .       PASS    het     2       2
67      VAR177_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr2    121747740       +       C       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA GLI2    MS      P1417H  .       PASS    het     2       2
71      rs199770435_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA     chr2    130872871       +       C       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA POTEF   SY      G184G   .       PASS    het     8
72      rs199695856_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA     chr2    132919171       +       A       G       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA ANKRD30BL       SY      H36H    .       PASS    het
73      rs111295191_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA     chr2    132919192       +       G       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA ANKRD30BL       SY      N29N    .       PASS    het
76      VAR186_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr2    167084231       +       T       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA SCN9A   SY      A1392A  .       PASS    het     3       19
77      VAR187_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr2    168100115       +       C       G       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA XIRP2   MS      T738S   .       PASS    het     9       49
78      VAR188_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr2    179343033       +       G       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA FKBP7   MS      A65D    .       PASS    het     3       7
79      VAR189_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr2    179544108       +       G       C       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA TTN     MS      P11234A .       PASS    het     3       17
82      VAR192_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr2    220074164       +       G       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA ZFAND2B MS      E92D    .       PASS    het     2       2
83      VAR193_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr2    220420892       +       C       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA OBSL1   MS      G1487W  .       PASS    het     3       9
84      rs191578275_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA     chr2    233273263       +       C       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA ALPPL2  MS      P279Q   .       PASS    het     3
86      VAR196_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr2    241815391       +       G       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA AGXT    SY      L272L   .       PASS    het     3       10
88      VAR198_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr3    9484995 +       C       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA SETD5   SG      R361*   .       PASS    het     3       18

96      VAR206_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr3    49848502        +       G       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA UBA7    MS      P382H   .       PASS    het     5       38
102     VAR212_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr3    58302669        +       G       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA RPP14   MS      L89F    .       PASS    het     3       30
103     VAR213_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr3    63981750        +       C       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA ATXN7   MS      T751K   .       PASS    het     3       13
104     rs146577101_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA     chr3    97868656        +       C       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA OR5H14  MS      R143W   .       PASS    het     4
107     rs58176285_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA      chr3    123419183       +       G       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA MYLK    SY      A1044A  .       PASS    het     18
108     VAR218_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr3    123419189       +       C       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA MYLK    SY      K1042K  .       PASS    het     23      174
115     VAR225_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr3    183753779       +       C       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA HTR3D   MS      P91T    .       PASS    het     4       48`

**File2:**

FBN1

HELZ

RALGPS2

DYNC1I2

NFE2L2

POSTN

INO80

I want those row which contains these genes.

Comment: I tried:

awk '$9 == "DENND5A" { print $0 }' nm02.txt

but using this command i have to write each single name to search again and again.

Answer (score 1):

So if I am following you correctly you just want to search `$9` in `file1` using the genes in `file2` and I add `MYLK` to the list I get:

Maybe:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$9 in A' file2 file1

**empty line** (since `MYLK` was found after the line break it is included
107     rs58176285_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA      chr3    123419183       +       G       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA MYLK    SY      A1044A  .       PASS    het     18
108     VAR218_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr3    123419189       +       C       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA MYLK    SY      K1042K  .       PASS    het     23      174
```

To remove the line break from the output:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$9 in A' file2 file1 | awk '!/^$/' 

107     rs58176285_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA      chr3    123419183       +       G       A       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA MYLK    SY      A1044A  .       PASS    het     18
108     VAR218_NM-02_TUMOR_DNA  chr3    123419189       +       C       T       NM-02_TUMOR_DNA MYLK    SY      K1042K  .       PASS    het     23      174
```

Comment: It is not working it only give one gene info not all the list of genes present in gene.txt file

Comment: Please post both input files, with desired output and make sure there are genes that will be found. I am not sure what is being asked.